# In the MDN documentation, why are some words red and the hyperlink does not work?

Tags: javascript

In MDN documentation, what is the meaning of some words being red and the hyperlink not working? Deprecated?

[image]

Comment: Because nobody has typed in a page with that title. It's a Wiki.

Comment: If you're not already I suggest using the US English version of the site. It offers the most documentation.

Comment: Hover it: "Page has not yet been created."

Answer (score 1):

This means that the documentation has not been written yet, either because it's a new feature or it's something that is deprecated from an old version. I would suggest you always using the US version of MDN as it's the most frequently updated